# Ionic: how to open popover triggered from two place on the same place?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, user-interface, ionic-framework

i have two buttons which are triggering the same popover. Problem is that if i click on the second button (big blue plus icon on the image below) is displayed popover in the place where is big icon but popover should be displayed in the right corner (as on the second image).

How can i do it please?

Code for triggering is following:

**BUTTON 1 (SMAL) : WORKING CORRECTLY**

```
<button ng-disabled="downloadInProgress" id="availableSoundsBtn" ng-click="openPopover($event,'popover_available_sounds.html')"  class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-circled"></button>
```

[image]

**BUTTON 2 (BIG) : IT DOES NOT WORKING CORRECTLY**

```
<div class="wrapperBigIcon" ng-if="selectedSounds.length == 0 && areFilesDownloaded == true">
        <h2>{{ 'CLICK_TO_ADD_TRACK' | translate }}</h2>
        <i ng-click="openPopover($event,'popover_available_sounds.html')" class="icon ion-plus-circled addCustomIcon"></i>
    </div>
```

[image]

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the name of the small button instead of $event will it open en the same place as when you press the small button.

Like this:

```
click="openPopover(availableSoundsBtn,'popover_available_sounds.html')"
```

Comment: How is your controller?, because this doesn't work for me